# How to ask a difficult neighbor not to play ball in front of house

Tags: conflicts, boundaries, neighbors

My problem is with my next door neighbor.  His grandson (approximately 5 years old) lives with him part time and they have started setting up one or two nets on the sidewalk and kicking a hard ball.  The objective of their game to get the ball in one of the nets.  They often miss and the ball has hit or nearly hit my car.  I am concerned that the ball will dent my car.  How do you suggest I deal with this situation?

Background: I have lived in my current home for the past 3.5 years.  In that time my neighbor has:

1. During the night, he attached his hose to the spigot in front of my house to fill his pool.
2. Put his garbage can directly behind my car, thereby preventing me from backing out of the driveway without moving the can.
3. Parked his truck so that it blocks part of my driveway, thereby making it difficult to drive in or out of the driveway.
4. Parked his truck in the driveway of a deceased neighbor.  When their heirs came to the house to get it ready to sell, they confronted him and he defended what he had done.

The list goes on.

Comment: You've said a lot about how he's "difficult" and what he's done but not anything about how he's reacted to being confronted. In item 4, you say that he "defended what he'd done" but that doesn't really tell us much... *personally* that doesn't sound like a huge deal. What are you afraid of? What will a solution have to take into consideration? Do you have a specific first-hand example of a time you've talked to this person and asked him to change his behavior and how he's responded, specifically?

Comment: Related: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/7034/102.

Comment: @Catija I say he is difficult based on seeing how he reacts to others.  He usually smiles and chuckles, says he was right it what he did, after a few rounds of this he will chuckle and just say "all right" and walk off.  His behavior doesn't seem to change after being confronted.  My concern is that he (or the grandchild) will put a dent the car.

Comment: @HDE 226868 Thanks for the link.  The "grownups" are the problem here too.

Comment: There is a park nearby.  Any suggestions on how to diplomatically ask or suggest that they play there?

Comment: @PICyPICyPICy It just sounds like your neighbour lacks respect for other neighbours.

Comment: As a father of a bunch of very active boys, I would find it hard to believe that a 5 year old could kick a soccer ball hard enough to actually put a dent a car.  Regarding the spigot - if I'm the one paying the water bill then I would have words with him over it (I know how much it costs to fill a pool) but that wasn't entirely clear.  If you aren't paying the water bill then I fail to see the problem.  If my neighbor blocked my driveway then we'd have a nice conversation about it.  Regardless, it sounds like you should loosen up a bit and actually just talk to your neighbor.

Comment: Both the boy and adult kick the ball.  I think they realize it could do damage  because the grandpa (guy in his 50s?) will temporarily park their cars away from where they are playing, and tells the boy not to kick near or toward their cars.  They do, however, kick the ball near/towards other peoples cars.  I've jokingly thought about playing soccer in the street so they say something, then telling them that perhaps we should both be mindful of each others cars.

Answer (score 2):

It's unlikely that a direct question is going to work here, based on past behaviour.

The first objective would probably be to make some form of meaningful connection. What need is he exhibiting by his actions? Does he live alone? If so, maybe his actions are a very backhanded way of trying to have some form of relationship? Or maybe he's been hurt or rejected by a previous neighbour, and is expecting that you will behave similarly?

Is it possible to offer your neighbour a drink, and a casual chat?

After some listening (with a view to understanding), he make take more kindly to a request along the lines of:

> When you and your grandson kick the ball on the sidewalk, I get scared because I like to get on with my neighbours. This might sound silly, but I'm worried that I'll get angry, if the ball hits my car and dents it. What do you think, when I say that?

The objective is to try to build rapport and understanding about where he's coming from. From there, to explore ways to get his (and grandson's) needs met - as well as yours. That might even involve offering to join in their game, **at the park**.